# Script set up via update-rc.d not being called on startup

Tags: ubuntu, bash

A script should be called on startup. I did what the internet told me, but it does not get called on startup.

Script in `/etc/init.d/my_script` simply uses `touch` to create files to see if it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

touch /home/db/called > /home/db/rc.log 2>&1

case "$1" in
  start)
    touch /home/db/started > /home/db/rc.log 2>&1
    ;;
  stop)
    touch /home/db/stopped > /home/db/rc.log 2>&1
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/test {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

The internet says that I simply have to run `sudo update-rc.d my_script defaults` to register it.

When run via `service my_script start` it works fine. The files are created as expected. But after reboot no files appear. So I assume the script isn't called at all, the log file `rc.log` also doesn't appear. When looking through the `rc*.d` folders (via `find /etc/rc* -name "*my_script*"`) there also doesn't seem to be a link to the script.

Maybe some other helpful info:

- Ubuntu 18.04 Server
- Script file in `/etc/init.d` is owned by root like every file there

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Solved it myself. For some reason `sudo update-rc.d my_script defaults` doesn't create the symlinks in the `/etc/rc*.d` folders (no errors given). The solution is to add the dependency header yourself and then running with `defaults` works, which makes no sense, because the `defaults` option is exactly for not having to do that. From `man update-rc.d`:

> update-rc.d foobar defaults
>
> The  equivalent  dependency header would have start and stop
>   dependencies on $remote_fs and $syslog, and start in runlevels 2-5 and
>   stop in runlevels 0, 1 and 6.

Edited bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Required-Start:    $all
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
### END INIT INFO

set -x

touch /home/db/es_called > /home/db/rc.log 2>&1

case "$1" in
  start)
    touch /home/db/es_started > /home/db/rc.log 2>&1
    ;;
  stop)
    touch /home/db/es_stopped > /home/db/rc.log 2>&1
    #killall -u db > /home/db/rc.log 2>&1
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/test {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

More info on dependency headers: https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: Thanks for this, that's odd and I still don't know why that's the case.         Most answers only insist on defaults option, only this solves my problem